# Issues with Textboxes Individually Hyperlinked to Slide with Matching Titles

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have put together an e-learning module.  I am still very new at vba though.  I am trying to make a dynamic main menu which contains multiple text boxes. If the text in a text box matches the title of a slide, that shape should then then be hyperlinked to the corresponding slide. Ideally, the text boxes on the Main Menu would contain the names of Sections and hyperlink to the first slide in the named section, but I couldn't figure that out, so instead I made the title of the first slide in each section match the text.  I've searched and searched and gotten as close as I could.  I am hoping someone can help me finish it. I have gotten past several errors, and have the text hyperlinked, however all linked take the user to the last slide in the presentation instead of the proper slide.  Thank you in advance for any guidance!!

Here is the code:

```
Sub TestMe()

'Original Source: http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/FAQ00056.htm

Dim aSl As Slide 'active slide
Dim dSl As Slide 'destination slide
Dim Slde As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape
Dim aSl_ID As Integer
Dim aSl_Index As Integer
Dim dSl_ID As Integer
Dim dSl_Index As Integer
Dim sTextToFind As String
Dim hypstart As String
Dim Titl As String

Set aSl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide 'active slide
aSl_Index = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex 'active slide index
' Set ActiveSld_Index =
' Set DestinationSld_ID = oSl.SlideID
' Set DestinationSld_Index = oSl.SlideIndex


        For Each oSh In aSl.Shapes

            'If IsSafeToTouchText(oSh) = True Then

                sTextToFind = oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text

                'loop through slides looking for a title that matches the text box value

                On Error Resume Next
                Set dSl = FindSlideByTitle(sTextToFind)

                ' get the information required for the hyperlink
                dSl_ID = CStr(dSl.SlideID)
                dSl_Index = CStr(dSl.SlideIndex)

                ' find the text string in the body
                hypstart = InStr(1, sTextToFind, sTextToFind, 1)

                'make the text a hyperlink
                With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(hypstart, Len(sTextToFind)).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink
                .SubAddress = dSl_ID & "," & dSl_Index & "," & sTextToFind

                End With

            'End If

        Next oSh

End Sub

Public Function FindSlideByTitle(sTextToFind As String) As Slide

'Source: http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/FAQ00056.htm

Dim oSl As Slide
Dim oSh As Shape

With ActivePresentation

    For Each oSl In .Slides

        For Each oSh In oSl.Shapes

            With oSh

                'If .HasTextFrame Then

                    'If Not .TextFrame.TextRange.Text Is Nothing Then

                    'myPres.Slides(1).Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange

                    On Error Resume Next

                    If UCase(.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) = UCase(sTextToFind) Then

                        'If UCase(.TextRange.Text) = UCase(sTextToFind) Then

                            Set FindSlideByTitle = oSl


                        'End If

                    End If

                'End If

            End With

        Next

    Next

End With

End Function

Public Function IsSafeToTouchText(pShape As Shape) As Boolean

'Source: http://www.steverindsberg.com/pptlive/FAQ00056.htm

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
If pShape.HasTextFrame Then
    If pShape.TextFrame.HasText Then
        ' Errors here if it's a bogus shape:
        If Len(pShape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text) > 0 Then
            ' it's safe to touch it
            IsSafeToTouchText = True
            Exit Function
        End If ' Length > 0
    End If ' HasText
End If ' HasTextFrame
Normal_Exit:
IsSafeToTouchText = False
Exit Function
ErrorHandler:
IsSafeToTouchText = False
Exit Function
End Function
```

Here is the revised code.  I have gone in circles and am now stuck.  Any suggestions are much appreciated!

After I restored the original function (FindSlideByTitle), I kept getting an error on  got an error on .textframe.textrange, making me think that the type of shape I used on my slide (freeform) needed TextFrame2, so I edited that, which fixed the error, but since then I've not been able to make the hyperlink work and have tried instead to use GoTo Slide by including the parent.

I even tried making an array of all freeform shapes on the slide, but I'm still new at this and perhaps I don't fully understand the concepts yet. As it currently stands, I don't get any errors, however, when I click one of the shapes, the shape's appearance changes from the click, but it doesn't go anywhere.

I have also included an image of the actual slide.

[image: Slide]

```
Sub TestLinkShapesToSlideTitles()


    Dim aSl, dSl, oSl As Slide 'active slide, destination slide
    Dim oSh As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim aSl_ID, dSl_ID As Integer
    Dim aSl_Index, dSl_Index As Long
    Dim dSl_Title, hypstart, Titl As String
    Dim sTextToFind As String
    Dim numshapes, numFreeformShapes As Long
    Dim FreeformShpArray As Variant
    Dim ShpRange As Object
    Dim oPres As Presentation


    Set aSl = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide 'active slide
    aSl_Index = Application.ActiveWindow.View.Slide.SlideIndex 'active slide index



    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'In this section I tried to make an array of all the freeform shapes on the slide, thinking that would help.

        With aSl.Shapes

            numshapes = .Count

            'Continues if there are Freeform shapes on the slide

            If numshapes > 1 Then

                numFreeformShapes = 0

                ReDim FreeformShpArray(1 To numshapes)

                For i = 1 To numshapes


                     'Counts the number of Freeform Shapes on the Slide

                    If .Item(i).Type = msoFreeformShape Then

                        numFreeformShapes = numFreeformShapes + 1

                        FreeformShpArray(numFreeformShapes) = .Item(i).Name

                    End If

                Next


                'Adds Freeform Shapes to ShapeRange

                If numFreeformShapes > 1 Then

                    ReDim Preserve FreeformShpArray(1 To numFreeformShapes)

                    Set ShpRange = .Range(FreeformShpArray)

                    'asRange.Distribute msoDistributeHorizontally, False

                End If

            End If

        End With


 ''''''''''''''''''''''''''

            On Error Resume Next

            'Loop through all the shapes on the active slide
            For Each oSh In aSl.Shapes

                If oSh.Type = msoFreeform Then 'oSh.Type = 5

                        'If oSh.HasTextFrame Then

                            If oSh.TextFrame2.HasText Then 'results in -1

                                With oSh

                                    sTextToFind = .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
                                        'sTextToFind results in "Where to Begin"
                                        '.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters results in "Learn the Lingo", which is the shape after Where to Begin.

                                End With

                            End If

                        'End If

                'If IsSafeToTouchText(oSh) = True Then

                    'With oSh.TextFrame

                        'sTextToFind = .TextRange.Characters.Text

                            'loop through slides looking for a title that matches the text box value
                            'For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides

                                'If oSl.Shapes.HasTitle Then

                                    'Titl = Slde.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange <<<<< I kept getting the error here...


                        On Error Resume Next
                        Set dSl = FindSlideByTitle_Original(sTextToFind)

                        ' get the information required for the hyperlink
                        dSl_Title = dSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange
                        dSl_ID = dSl.SlideID
                        dSl_Index = dSl.SlideIndex

                            With oSh

                                .ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Parent.Parent.View.GoToSlide dSl_Index, msoFalse  'Go to slide and don't reset animations

                            End With

                            ' find the text string in the body
                            'hypstart = InStr(1, sTextToFind, dSl_Title, 1)

                            'make the text a hyperlink
                            'With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters(hypstart, Len(sTextToFind)).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink

                                '.SubAddress = dSl_ID & "," & dSl_Index & "," & sTextToFind

                            'End With

                    'End With

                    End If

                'End If

            Next oSh

End Sub

Public Function FindSlideByTitle_Original(sTextToFind As String) As Slide

    'Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038952/vba-powerpoint-select-a-slide-by-name

    Dim oSl As Slide

    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With oSl.Shapes.Title.TextFrame
            If .HasText Then
                If UCase(.TextRange.Text) = UCase(sTextToFind) Then
                    Set FindSlideByTitle_Original = oSl
                End If
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Function
```

Comment: I'd start by restoring the original code from FindSlideByTitle (which isn't at the link you posted ... try here instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25038952/vba-powerpoint-select-a-slide-by-name)

Comment: @Jenn ... the code works for creating hyperlinks from a slide with shapes containing text which corresponds to slide title text. I can't see any way to create hyperlinks to sections, so linking to the first slide in each section seems like the best outcome. I assume that was the scope of your question?

Comment: @Techno Dabbler Yes, that's right. Do you know how I can do this? As of now, the only way I could figure was to make a title slide for each section, just for the hyperlink purpose.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg I will try your suggestion and revise my references link. Thanks!

Comment: @Jenn You're welcome.  Please post your revised code and results when you've done that.

Comment: @Steve Rindsberg I am posting my revised code...